# jQuery doenst work in a javascript ruby tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I've put this problem up before but i way I was trying to do it was terrible to say the least. I need to call a jQuery show() method when a certain argument is fulfilled in a Ruby loop. My idea was a Javascript tag similar to the example. But for some reason jQuery does not work in this javascript tag. I can't think of a better way of doing this than the one im currently trying to do.

code:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
            <% if record.task.project.name == "SKIP"%>
            <%= javascript_tag :defer => 'defer' do -%>
                $('.toil.).show();
            <% end -%>
            <% else %>
<%= javascript_tag :defer => 'defer' do -%>
                    $('.toil.).hide();
                <% end -%>
```

this loop works and ive tested that. Is there a better way of trying to what i want? If there is a project with name skip then a class needs to be shown... if there arent any then it needs to be hidden. Seems simple but complex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really explain the nature of what needs to be hidden or shown, so there's a bunch of ways to go about this.

If it's a section of HTML per-record, just don't render it in the loop:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <% if record.task.project.name != "SKIP"%>
    All the HTML
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If it's something you still need rendered because it might become visible later, set a class:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <% skipIt = record.task.project.name == "SKIP" ? "display: none;" : "" %>
    <span style="<%= skipIt %>">
      All the HTML
    </span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If it's just a flag to be used later:

```
<% skipIt = false %>
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <% skipIt = true if record.task.project.name == "SKIP" %>
    All the HTML
  <% end %>
<% end %>
...
$(function() {
  <% if skipIt %>
    $(".toil").hide();
  <% end %>
});
```

Etc. Lots of ways. Depends on what you really need, which we don't know.

(In most of the examples above, functionality should probably be moved into a partial or at least a helper.)

Comment: What im trying to do is show a few rows of a table if there is data in those table cells, these are populated by the records with SKIP as a name. So if there are no records than those rows do not need to be shown so they are hidden...

Comment: Then the first one--why use JavaScript to hide something that doesn't need to be rendered in the first place?

Comment: they do need to be rendered because the values may not be there but the user can input them so the fields need to be there. There is a Jquery toggle button that the user uses to show/hide the fields again.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, there is a typo there:

```
 $('.toil.).show();
```

You are missing a single quote at the end of the selectors.

They should be for example:

```
 $('.toil').show();
```

That will show all the elements with a css class named "toil". Javascript and jQuery work with HTML and CSS, I have the feeling you are trying to read or manipulate ruby tags, and that won't work, because JS is executed when the data arrives to the browser, so the ruby tags have been already processed and converted to html just in case :D

Comment: yep sorry that was a typo for just the question, in my code is the normal way. Your second part is interesting and ive never thought of that. But surely if the ruby is looping around and it gets to the point where it needs to call the js it will call it? or are you saying that the browser calls it and therefore even if the ruby looped and hit it, it wouldnt run ?

Comment: @spartan2417, Ruby runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. All the Ruby is gone before your JavaScript is even a glimmer in the browser's eye.

Comment: Exactly as @Dave Newton said. When I started in this business, in order to understand it well I always thought about ruby, jsp and asp.net as "html generators", they are just webservices that generates html from the input that the browser send. In the other hand, javascript is a scripting language that runs on the browser, and the browser only see what the server has generated, so JS can only interact with HTML and CSS, cannot see ruby tags, asp.net tags, C# code or anyting like that.